# How to dynamically render a specific amount of rows and columns in React with Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to render a board for the game Wheel of Fortune using bootstrap in React. If a random phrase is generated I would like a new row to render every time there is a space in the string. For example: "lets go" would render "lets (new row) go" on the UI. In my code, I call a  function to render each letter in a box. However, I'm not getting anything to show up on the UI.

I also tried splitting the array and mapping it with (screenshot of this approach below):

```
splicedArray: Array(Math.ceil(this.state.charactersArray.length / this.state.itemsPerRow)).fill().map(() => this.state.charactersArray.splice(0, this.state.itemsPerRow)),
```

((in render))

```
 {this.state.splicedArray.map((character) => <Square value={character}/>)}
```

**Here is my code for the Board:**

```
import Button from "@restart/ui/esm/Button";
import React from "react";

import { Component } from "react";
import { ListGroup, breakpoint, idx, Card, Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Square from "./square.component.js";
import {character} from "./square.component"


class Board extends Component{
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            randomPhrase: "Placeholder",
            wordArray: ["temp"],
            charactersArray: ["temp"],
            guess: "t",
            index: 0
        };
    }
    phrases=["dont let the cat out of the bag", "lets hit the road", "lets rock and roll"]

    //generates a random word from the word list in state then splits it by character into an array
    //this array is called below to generate square objects
    randomWordGenerator = () => {
            this.setState({ randomPhrase: this.phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.phrases.length)],
                            wordArray: this.state.randomPhrase.split(' '),   
                            charactersArray: this.state.randomPhrase.split('')           
                            
    })};

    renderRows = () => {
        const rows = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < this.state.charactersArray.length; i++) {
            if(this.state.charactersArray[i] === " ") {
                this.state.index++;
               rows.push(
                   <Row>
                       {this.renderColumns(this.state.index)}
                   </Row>
               )       
               this.state.index = 0;
            }
            else {
               this.state.index++;
            }
        }
    }

    renderColumns = (index) => {
        const columns = [];

        for(let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
            columns.push(
                <Col>
                {this.renderSquares}
                </Col>
            )
        }
    }

    renderSquares = () => {
       return this.state.charactersArray.map((character) => character === " " ?  <Card style={{ height: '5rem', width: '4rem' }} className="bg-success justify-content-center text-center border border-dark">
       Logo
       </Card> : 
       <Square value={character}/>)
    }

    render(){
        return(                   
            <ListGroup vertical>
               
                <Button variant="outline-generate" size="lg" onClick={this.randomWordGenerator}>Generate</Button>
                <Button variant="outline-generate" size="lg" onClick={this.renderRows}>Render</Button>
               {this.state.splicedArray}
                
            </ListGroup>

           
        );
    }
}
export default Board;
```

**And here is my code for the Square:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "@restart/ui/esm/Button";
import { Card, ListGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { filter } from 'lodash';
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Square extends Component{  
 

    render(){
        return(
            <ListGroup.Item className="mx-1 p-0 mt-1 border border-dark" variant="light">
                
              <Card style={{height: '5rem', width: '4rem', fontSize: '4rem'}} className="text-dark rounded justify-content-center text-center border border-dark">
             
              {this.props.value}    
                
              </Card>
            </ListGroup.Item>
        )
    }
}

export default Square;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Output Screenshot: When I hit render a dark border forms behind the button.
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm9Qq.png)

Ouput Screenshot when splitting the array:
[Splitting the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhclX.png)

Comment: Just split the string and use map. What's the problem?

Comment: I tried splitting the string with Array(Math.ceil(this.state.charactersArray.length / this.state.itemsPerRow)).fill().map(() => this.state.charactersArray.splice(0, this.state.itemsPerRow)) and then mapping it but I think because the <Square/> function is inside a listgroup, it is constrained to the listgroup properties and cannot render as rows. So I'm trying to use loops instead, but everything is rendering on top of one another. I'll add an output image to my post!

Comment: An image would be helpful

Comment: Just added an image! Maybe it's a formatting issue?